# sending HTML email with a variable in the URL

Tags: php, html, email, variables

I am using the following script to send a dynamic page (php) as a html email... the page being emailed uses a variable in the URL to determine what record is shown from a database

```
<?

 $evid = $_GET['evid'];

    $to  = 'dj@mail.com';
$subject = 'A test email!';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Put your HTML here
$message = file_get_contents('http://www.url.co.uk/diary/i.php?evid=2');

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

as you can see the html file being emailed has a evid variable... if i set this to $evid and try to send the variable when running the current script I get an error... does anyone know of a way round this?

hope i explained that clear enough
Rob

Comment: Where is `$evid` in your email? What's the error?

Comment: relentless: if i add the variable i get the word Error emailed rather than the page:

Comment: if i do the following it doesnt work:   $message = file_get_contents('http://www.url.co.uk/diary/i.php?evid=$evid');

Comment: there is no error from the php script but the email displays the word "Error" as opposed to the message its supposed to display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP won't evaluate variables in single-quotes strings.

```
$variable = "Hello World!";
echo '$variable'; //$variable
echo "$variable"; //Hello World!
```

Either move to double-quoted strings, or use the concantation operator (`.`):

```
echo 'string' . $variable; //stringHello World!
```

Comment: are you saying i should change to: 
     $evid = $_GET["evid"];
as that doesnt seem to work either

Comment: @RobCrouch: I'm saying you should change to `"http://www.url.co.uk/diary/i.php?evid=$evid"` (and not `'http://...'`).

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating the variable to the end of the url string like so:

```
$message = file_get_contents('http://www.url.co.uk/diary/i.php?evid=' . $evid);
```

Work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = file_get_contents('http://www.url.co.uk/diary/i.php?evid='.$evid);
```